# Sentence correction explaination

Tags: articles, questions

There is a sentence in my homework that I don't know how to do it :

I **spent** my holiday in **a** country **which** is **peaceful** and picturesque

The instruction tells me to correct one of the bold words and the answer is " a " but I don't understand why and I don't know how to correct it either.

Comment: Ok, we are not supposed to do homework here (East Coast, US) but it is late and I feel sorry for you. I spent my holiday in a peaceful, picturesque country. Next time, please try and ask a more sensible question with context and your own explanation first.

Comment: There's nothing in the sentence that needs to be corrected.

Comment: in the country.

Comment: @Zhang, **the** might work of there were a comma after **country**. Without the comma, **which is...** is a defining relative clause, and can only be used with **a**... unless there is only one country in the world that is peaceful and picturesque.

Comment: @JavaLatte, country here is nation, it is supposed to be village. If the author wants to say in another country. It should be "in another country" or "in a foreign country."

Comment: @Zhang, as James K says in his answer, there is no need to say "another country" or "a foreign country". Anyway, the speaker might not necessarily be talking about a foreign country at all: the speaker could be talking about his native country, or the country that he is currently in.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not well asked.

There are two meanings of "country".  One is "State" the other is "countryside". Both reading are possible. There is no need to say "foreign country" or similar, though this can prevent ambiguity

In the first sense you would probably use "a", and so no correction is needed.

In the second sense you would probably use "the" and insert a comma. You would also probably use "countryside" to avoid ambiguity.

> I spent my holiday in **the** countryside, which is peaceful and picturesque.

However as asked the question is unanswerable, because *there is nothing in the sentence that needs changing*.